# Find apache 2.4. install files for windows

Tags: apache, webserver

I'm trying to install apache 2.4. at windows but i can't find the nessasary files at official site (here apache.org). What i need is apache 2.4 for windows 64 (or 32). Can anybody to help me and give the refference to the page with the files.

Answer (score 0):

From [Downloading Apache for Windows](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/platform/windows.html#down):

> The Apache HTTP Server Project itself does not provide binary releases of software, only source code. Individual committers may provide binary packages as a convenience, but it is not a release deliverable.
>
> If you cannot compile the Apache HTTP Server yourself, you can obtain a binary package from numerous binary distributions available on the Internet.